# Анимация сворачивания текста в абривиатуру

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Я хочу сделать с помощью css (возможно js и jquery) анимацию разворачивания текста на hover.
Например есть надпись "YT" и при наведении превращается в YouTube, есть ли готовые примеры такой анимации, или советы как это сделать

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RwpBwNe если transition нужен то для каждого второго span подобрать индивидуальный width

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо очень помогло)

Comment: @MaximLensky, ваше решение не учитывает кернинг символов и в режиме аббревитуры рядом с буквами Y и T видны краешки соседних букв.

Comment: @Инквизитор я ни чего не вижу ... ни каких  краешков ..

Comment: @MaximLensky, см. мой второй ответ - увеличил для наглядности с помощью трансформации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы наверное сделал что-то вроде:

```
<span class="expand-abbr">
<span class="abbr">Y</span><span class="word">ou</span>
<span class="abbr">T</span><span class="word">ube</span></span>
```

При ховере на expand-abbr отображать span.word, которые по умолчанию скрыты. А как отображать, это уже дело вкуса, можно CSS (transition) или через js

Answer (score 3):

А я бы решил иначе. Если придется, например, заполнять из базы данных, то не понадобится резать строку на части.

```css
.abbreviation {background:pink;padding:0.5em;}

.abbreviation:before {content:attr(short)}
.abbreviation:hover:before {content:attr(long)}
```

```html
<span class="abbreviation" short="YT" long="Котики"></span><br/><br/>
<span class="abbreviation" short="FB" long="Какая-то фигня"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для @MaximLensky: в режиме аббревитуры рядом с буквами Y и T видны краешки соседних букв.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left:100px;
  transform: scale(5);
}

p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}

.flex:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p><span>Y</span><span>ou</span> </p>
  <p><span>T</span><span>ube</span> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: я тоже самое сделал и у меня нету хвостиков - https://ibb.co/rxD4Q07 - смотри

Comment: вот видео записал : https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0ms57hkhdbes27/finish.mp4

Comment: у тебя там шрифт не Таймс.  если шрифт будет другой (Times New Roman, например, который задается в браузерах по умолчанию если контент не обстилен другим шрифтом), то буквы накладываются на границы спанов и видны края. - https://ibb.co/q5WHppw

Comment: у меня там вообще не подключен шрифт ... в общем х.з  у меня всё тип топ

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RwpBwNe  вот шрифт подключил

Comment: Все, снимаю возражения. У меня в коде почему-то `p span:nth-of-type(2)` имеет  `width: 1px;`, хотя копировал из первой версии вашего пена. Сорри. В любом случае, я бы делал это иначе, о чем и дал другой ответ =)